# Finding Shortest Path function in Neo4j applied to real life problems

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-databases

[image: Image showing the graph model with the nodes and relationships]

Questions

1.) For the “General Computing” pathway, which module has highest impact
(i.e., is the compulsory pre-requisite of the most modules)?

2.) If a student fails a particular module in first year, display pathways that
will take minimum 4 years to complete the course (Note: all modules on
the pathway need to be done to complete a course).

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This may work, if I understand your data model:

   ```
   MATCH (m:Module)<-[r:PRE_REQUISITE]-(:Module)-[:ON]->(pw:Pathway)
   WHERE pw.title = 'General Computing' AND r.type = 'Compulsory'
   RETURN m, COUNT(*) AS impact
   ORDER by impact DESC
   LIMIT 1
   ```
2. You have not provided enough information. We do not know how long each module takes to complete and how often it is offered, whether the `level` property needs to be considered and how, what other `type` values there are and what they all really mean, etc. And it seems that one would really want a  *maximum* of 4 years, not a *minimum*.

Comment: Hi,thank you for your response. this is from a practice test and i have copied the question as is. Assuming this follows the normal university modules and pathway structure i suppose @cybersam

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer for the first question should be like this:

match (module)<-[r:PRE_REQUISITE{type: "Compulsory"}]-(m:Module)-[:ON]->(p:Pathway{title: "General Computing"})
return module.title as ModuleName, count(*) as highest_impact

order by highest_impact desc
limit 1